# Find cases of List["str"] but not List[str] = ["a"]

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to check for outdated type hints syntax in a Python codebase.

I would like to catch cases such as

```
List["str"]
```

which could just be

```
List[str]
```

I've written the following regular expression:

```
List\[.*\".+\".*\]
```

however, it also catches the following string:

```
List[str] = ["a"]
```

which I don't want to catch.

Examples of strings I want to catch:

- List["str"]
- Union[int, "np.ndarray"]

How could I modify my regular expression accordingly?

Comment: You have a variable named "List"? That seems like a bigger problem... Anyways, you should  probably use ast parsing instead of regexes for more accuracy

Comment: it's part of a type annotation (e.g. `my_list: List[str] = ["a"]`)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: That can be fragile but might do for your scenario: `List\[[^][]*"[^"]*"[^][]*]`

Comment: Or like `\w+\[[^][]*](?!\s*=)` https://regex101.com/r/UTMnNY/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the example strings, you could match either List or Union followed by using a negated character class matching from the opening till closing square bracket that can not be followed by an equals sign.

```
\b(?:List|Union)\[[^][]*](?!\s*=)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b(?:List|Union)` Match either List or union preceded by a word boundary to prevent them being part of a longer word.
- `\[[^][]*]` Match from `[` till `]` not matching either of them in between using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- `(?!\s*=)` Assert no `=` sign to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UTMnNY/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Just change the dots to a character class excluding only `]`:

`List\[[^\]]*\".+?\"[^\]]*\]`

Comment: You do not need to escape `]` and `"` here, in a Python regex. Also, it [matches](https://regex101.com/r/BGpCkk/2) `List["str"] = List[int,"str"]` as a single match, but that is probably fine for OP.

Comment: compatibility with other regex engines(`[^]` is legal in JS regex) for usage in vscode find+replace for instance.